# stop passing function from parent to child elements javascript

Tags: javascript

I want parent element to disappear when clicking on it

But I want also all child elements to stop implement this function as when clicking on it the parent element hide

I want a solution in Vanilla javascript

```
var listmenu = document.querySelector(".list-overlay");// this list menu nested in overlay element but when click on it also parent element hide but i want no action when click on it  

overlay.addEventListener("click",hide);


  function hide(){
      overlay.classList.add("hide");

  }
```

Comment: Please show your code so we can assist you.

Comment: You should use event.stopPropagation() in your child elements.

Comment: i show the code Dear Emmanuel Sayson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `stopPropagation` to stop the event from the child elements bubbling to the parent element.

I added an example here.

```js
function hideParent() {
  document.getElementById('parent').style.display = 'none';
}

function onChildClick1(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}

document.getElementById('child1').addEventListener('click', onChildClick1);
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

#child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


#child2 {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onclick="hideParent()">
  THIS IS THE PARENT
  <div id="child1">
    CHILD: STOP PROPAGATION <!-- will *not* trigger parent and remain visible -->
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    CHILD: DEFAULT BEHAVIOR <!-- will trigger parent and hide -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, how is this a working sample? The `onClick()` handler is only bound to `#child1` so what does it mean if I click `#child2`?

Comment: @AhmedMohamed I'm concerned this answer may be wrong. `stopPropogation` prevents events from bubbling _from the child up the DOM_, not from parent down. From MDN: [However, stopEvent also calls an event object method, event.stopPropagation, which keeps the event from bubbling any further up into the DOM.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)

Comment: ok i will check your mdn even though the function working properly but may be your MDN is Best Practice @ stealththeninja

Comment: @stealththeninja I would like to show how it works when the elements are bound to `stopPropagation`. So `child1` was bound to `stopPropagation` so it doesn't trigger the click event of the parent element, but `child1` was not bound to `stopPropagation` so it triggers the click event of the parent element.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. The question asks "how to block parent-to-child" (I don't think that's how event bubbling works), and this answer gives "how to block child-to-parent" (which is probably correct). The question would benefit from using a minimal **and complete** example to show the problem (@AhmedMohamed) , we're guessing that this is the correct fix given the description and partial code.